# Mercenary Attack Rating

Tags: diablo-ii

I've read online that mercs in D2 have an AR, even though we can't see it. My question is: Can I put diamonds into their armor and helm to raise it, or can it not be changed?

Answer (score 2):

What I have managed to find is a table of stats, and a "calculator" tool.

There is nothing specific about the effect of Diamonds on the Hireling's AR, but the Tool does have this subnote stating that stats can be affected by gear (emphasis mine):

> Note that resistances are capped at 75 **unless the hireling wears something that increases max resistances**. For that purpose, the calculator will show the value before the cap.

It does state *resistances*, but I don't know if that does mean it *can* affect AR as well.

- [Hirelings Stat Calculator](http://www.lurkerlounge.com/spirea/Hirelings/Stats.shtml)
- [Imgur link to Stat Spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6yZN.jpg)
- [Original Discussion on Blizzard Forum](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/d2r/t/mercenary-attack-rating-stats-where-can-i-find-them/126798/8)